# How to handle NULL Bytes in JSON Column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql

I recieved some NULL Bytes like `\u0000`.  It fails with 'Unsupported Unicode Escape Sequence' in PostgreSQL

Any idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Found out, from versioj 9.4 onwards, they disallowed NULL Bytes `\u0000`.